# Foreign Key Constraints - DB won't import. - Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, foreign-keys

I followed the advice here, but I'm still running into the same issues after importing my database to a local XAMPP installation.

My sql dump is wrapped in these tags:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
// FULL DB DUMP
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Even still, I get this error message:

```
Error
SQL query:
ALTER TABLE `mage_catalog_eav_attribute` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY ( `attribute_id` ) REFERENCES `mage_eav_attribute` ( `attribute_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDB_NAME`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-2e0_5a'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `mage_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DE)
```

Can anyone help me understand what else I would need to disable these checks, or prevent this error?

I am running Magento 1.4.2, and importing with phpmyadmin via xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not import via Phpmyadmin. It usually works really bad. Use the command line.

This should work:

```
cat your_mysql_dump_file.sql | mysql -uyour_user -p myDB_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks, this bypassed the issues I was experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

When I took a phpMyAdmin MySQL export and put it into another phpMyAdmin interface, I found that pre-existing tables caused the constraint problem. Deleting the tables was also problematic because of the key constraints.

When importing, make sure the present database tables do not have key constraints. I did this by dropping the tables.

To drop the tables, I turned off the constraint check by executing SQL code like this in the SQL screen of phpMyAdmin for the database in question.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE civicrm_acl;
... all of the problem tables with their constraints...
DROP TABLE civicrm_worldregion;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

(the latter SET is good housekeeping)

Then, I was able to do my import. When I looked at my MySQL export, it had added the constraints at the end of the import, after the data is in place. If your MySQL import puts the constraints in before the data is in place, that will prevent the import from working completely.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I will try this method first next time.